# Refer variable in script file from child process

Tags: bash, environment-variables

There is `a.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

foo=':bar baz:'
declare varvar=aaaaaa
export xyz=abc

echo "$foo ok"
hoge=huga env piyo=alice bash -i
```

Run `./a.sh` (`|` is cursor, `>` is prompt):

```
:bar baz: ok
> |
```

There is the input:

```
echo "foo: '$foo'"
echo "varvar: '$varvar'"
echo "xyz: '$xyz'"
echo "hoge: '$hoge'"
echo "piyo: '$piyo'"
```

Expected output:

```
> echo "foo: '$foo'"
foo: ':bar baz:'
> echo "varvar: '$varvar'"
varvar: 'aaaaaa'
> echo "xyz: '$xyz'"
xyz: 'abc'
> echo "hoge: '$hoge'"
hoge: 'huga'
> echo "piyo: '$piyo'"
piyo: 'alice'
> |
```

Actual output:

```
> echo "foo: '$foo'"
foo: ''
> echo "varvar: '$varvar'"
varvar: ''
> echo "xyz: '$xyz'"
xyz: 'abc'
> echo "hoge: '$hoge'"
hoge: 'huga'
> echo "piyo: '$piyo'"
piyo: 'alice'
> |
```

How do I get `$foo` and `$varvar` to display correctly?

Comment: Export them? You're already doing that with `xyz`. Or make the assignment as with `hoge` or `piyo`. It's unclear what the question is as you have the answer in your code.

Comment: Do I need to export the variables to display them? Is there any way to display them without exporting? I would like to use it for debugging.

Comment: Do you know how environment variables work? Child processes inherit environment variables. Other variables are not inherited. You create environment variables for a child process to see in the various ways you show, with `export`, by assigning them at the start of a command's command line or by setting them in the arguments to `env` when using that tool to launch the command.

Comment: It gave me an understanding of environment variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix `a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -a
foo=':bar baz:'
declare varvar=aaaaaa
export xyz=abc

echo "$foo ok"
hoge=huga env piyo=alice bash -i
```

It lets all variables export.